# how to display original php variable

Tags: php

I have modified a variable in a short script, now all the varibles have been modified. anyway to resolve this?

```
<?php $var_header_services="Electrical Services"; ?>

<a  href="/<?php $var_header_services = preg_replace('/\s+/','', $var_header_services);         
                            $var_header_services = strtolower($var_header_services);
                            echo $var_header_services; ?>.php">
        <?php echo $var_header_services; ?></a>
```

so everything works as it should in the first part but when i want to echo the variable again as in:

```
<?php echo $var_header_services; ?>
```

it echos " electricalservices" and i want it to echo "Electrical Services" as originally created.

Answer (score 1):

use on other name for the replaced

```
<?php $var_header_services="Electrical Services"; ?>

<a  href="/<?php $var_header_services_replaced = preg_replace('/\s+/','', $var_header_services);         
                            $var_header_services_replaced = strtolower($var_header_services_replaced);
                            echo $var_header_services_replaced; ?>.php">
        <?php echo $var_header_services; ?></a>
```